# BigQuery API vs BigQuery Tools

Tags: google-bigquery

I am  looking at extracting data from BigQuery and I have found out that it can be extracted using API or tools. Does any one know the advantage of using API over tools?

One of the things I can think of API advantage is that, with API data extraction can be scheduled for fixed time intervals.Are there any other advantage of using API's?

Basically I want to know when to use API vs tools.

Answer (score 1):

To state it explicitly, the BigQuery tools including the BQ CLI, the Web UI, and even [third party tools](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/third-party-tools) are leveraging the BigQuery API to enable whatever functionality they expose.  Google also provides [client libraries](https://developers.google.com/discovery/libraries) for many popular programming languages that make working with the API more straightforward.

Your question then becomes whether your particular needs are best served by using one of these tools or building your own integration with the API.  If you're simply loading data into tables once an hour, perhaps a local cron job that calls the BQ CLI tool is sufficient.  If you're streaming some kind of event record into a table as they happen, the API route may be more appropriate as you're integrating more deeply into your own software stack.